# Incremental Game Error

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an incremental game but when I load the game it adds more decimals and counts up to "infinite".
I made a codepen so you can see the error for yourself
Try and click the picture a couple of times and press save and load.
Why are the number of quickscopes going up like that?

[The Codepen](http://codepen.io/multiboy/pen/azdgma)

```
    var faze = 0;
function fazeClick(number){
    faze = faze + number;
    document.getElementById('faze').innerHTML = faze;
}
var mntDew = 0;
function buyDew(){
    var mntDewCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,mntDew));
    if(faze >= mntDewCost){
        mntDew = mntDew +1;
        faze = faze - mntDewCost;
        document.getElementById('mntDew').innerHTML = mntDew;
        document.getElementById('faze').innerHTML = faze;
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.2,mntDew));
    document.getElementById('mntDewCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem('faze', JSON.stringify(faze));
    localStorage.setItem('mntDew', JSON.stringify(mntDew));
    //add more here
};
function load(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('mntDew')){
        faze = localStorage.getItem('faze');
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem('faze')){
        faze = localStorage.getItem('faze');
    };
    //add more here
};
function deleteSave(){
    localStorage.removeItem("save");
};

window.setInterval(function(){
    fazeClick(mntDew);
}, 1000);


// <button type="button" onClick="buyDew()">Buy Mountain Dew</button> #buyCursor
//Mountain Dew: <span id="mntDew">0</span><br/> #cursors
//cost: <span id="mntDewCost">10</span> #cursorCost
```

Comment: you should not deal with the questions that you still open before making new ones?

Comment: I forgot to close it, but as you can see if you've seen it... I've gotten a new issue. :)

Comment: OOOH baby a triple! Love your codepen ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responsible of your 'bug' is the following instructions:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    fazeClick(mntDew);
}, 1000);
```

Your counter start to increment because the onclick of 'Buy Mountain Dew' button increment the value of `mntDew var', before of that the set interval call fazeClick(0);

I am really sorry, but I'm not able to understand what you want to achieve